# Bludgeon Brawl & Puresteel Paladin

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Puresteel Paladin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Puresteel%20Paladin) and [Bludgeon Brawl](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bludgeon%20Brawl) in play.  I play an [Ichor Wellspring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ichor%20Wellspring).  How many cards do I draw, one or two?

Puresteel Paladin says

> Whenever an Equipment enters the battlefield under your control, you may draw a card.

Bludgeon Brawl says

> Each noncreature, non-Equipment artifact is an Equipment with equip X and "Equipped creature gets +X/+0," where X is that artifact's converted mana cost.

and Ichor Wellspring says

> When Ichor Wellspring enters the battlefield or is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, draw a card.

Comment: As a side question, what's a good way of linking to card images, as I've seen people do in recent MtG questions?  Would certainly make my question more aesthetically appealing!

Comment: Personally I would just just link to the cards on gatherer.wizards.com …

Comment: There was actually a deck using that very interaction featured on Channel Fireball: http://www.channelfireball.com/articles/channel-conley-deck-doctor-7-1/

Comment: @David: Yes, I watched some of those videos.  (Conley may not be the best player on that site, but he's definitely the most entertaining.)  This interaction didn't come up during the time I was watching, but I was wondering what would have happened if it did...

Comment: I have been linking to images on gatherer and rather than choosing the insert a link icon, choose insert a picture, and change from your computer to web.  I believe this is preferred as it appears to copy the image to the stack imgur space, and it can tell when you're pointing to the same image someone else has in the past.  In time, the whole library might end up ported over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first I thought you would only draw one card. But I think the rules have been tweaked on this since I last did dastardly stuff like this…

> 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn't include the word "card," "spell," "source," or "scheme," it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

Thus the [Bludgeon Brawl](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218055) enchantment only refers to noncreature, non-Equipment cards already on the battlefield. It's a continuous effect. Note it *does not* affect cards in your hand or spells on the stack. That's why I thought maybe you'd only draw one card.

But here's the relevant rules. Emphasis is mine.

> 603.6b Continuous effects that modify characteristics of a permanent **do so the moment the permanent is on the battlefield** (and not before then). **The permanent is never on the battlefield with its unmodified characteristics.** Continuous effects don't apply before the permanent is on the battlefield, however (see rule 603.6e).
>   Example: If an effect reads "All lands are creatures" and a land card is played, **the effect makes the land card into a creature the moment it enters the battlefield, so it would trigger abilities that trigger when a creature enters the battlefield.** Conversely, if an effect reads "All creatures lose all abilities" and a creature card with an enters-the-battlefield triggered ability enters the battlefield, that effect will cause it to lose its abilities the moment it enters the battlefield, so the enters-the-battlefield ability won't trigger.

603.6b is confirmed and reframed by 611.3c:

> 611.3c Continuous effects that modify characteristics of permanents **do so simultaneously with the permanent entering the battlefield.** They don't wait until the permanent is on the battlefield and then change it. Because such effects apply as the permanent enters the battlefield, **they are applied before determining whether the permanent will cause an ability to trigger when it enters the battlefield.**
>   Example: A permanent with the static ability "All white creatures get +1/+1" is on the battlefield. A creature spell that would normally create a 1/1 white creature instead creates a 2/2 white creature. The creature doesn't enter the battlefield as 1/1 and then change to 2/2.

Therefore, guess what [Johnny](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtgcom/daily/mr11b)? When [Ichor Wellspring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=213737) enters the battlefield, due to the continuous effect of the Bludgeon Brawl, it thinks that it has always been an Equipment and triggers [Puresteel Paladin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227504)'s ability! You get to draw two cards!

Comment: PS. When you create this crazy deck, don't forget to add [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50527) for the lulz.

Comment: Note that to turn all your permanents into equipment as they come into play, you'll need to cast the Lattice first. See rule 613. We're into the serious mind-bending territory here. I want to see your Puresteel Paladin *equip the Bludgeon Brawl* and swing with +3/+0.

Comment: Let's not forget he can equip with the Lattice too for +6/+0!  Sadly all your now-Artifact lands won't give you a power boost when they're equipped, but I recommend equipping all of them to your Kemba, Kha Regent anyway...

Comment: And then play the Simple half of Pure // Simple to wipe out most of the board, just because you CAN.