# Can I use Mentor of the Meek on small guys with buffed stats?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Vanquisher's Banner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVanquisher%27s%5d%2b%5bBanner%5d) and [The Immortal Sun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Immortal%20Sun%5d) on the battlefield, and a 1/1 creature enters the battlefield under my control, assuming the creature matches the creature type I declared with [Vanquisher's Banner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVanquisher%27s%5d%2b%5bBanner%5d), would I be able to pay 2 mana and use [Mentor of the Meek](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMentor%20of%20the%20Meek%5d) to draw an additional card?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bludgeon Brawl & Puresteel Paladin](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/bludgeon-brawl-puresteel-paladin), question appears different, but the answers, answer this question as well.

Comment: I'd rather keep it open as this is a more legible question for the general case.

Comment: Where is the 2 mana coming from?

Comment: @Acccumulation Would it affect the answer? I think we can assume that the player has enough mana, and that there are no spending restrictions.

Comment: @John no it's a different enough case that I would call it different.

Comment: @Acccumulation Does it matter? The question is more "Does the ability trigger" not "How do I pay for it" and the answer as given very well by Rishaal, is no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Both abilities of [Vanquisher's Banner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVanquisher%27s%5d%2b%5bBanner%5d) and The [Immortal Sun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bImmortal%20Sun%5d) that gives creatures you control +1/+1 are static abilities.

> 611.3. A continuous effect may be generated by the static ability of an object.
>
> 611.3a A continuous effect generated by a static ability isn’t “locked in”; it applies at any given moment to whatever its text indicates.
>
> 611.3b The effect applies at all times that the permanent generating it is on the battlefield or the object generating it is in the
> appropriate zone.
> *Example: A permanent with the static ability “All
> white creatures get +1/+1” generates an effect that continuously gives
> +1/+1 to each white creature on the battlefield. If a creature becomes white, it gets this bonus; a creature that stops being white loses it.*

But what comes first when the 1/1 creature enters the battlefield zone. The trigger from [Mentor of the Meek](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMentor%20of%20the%20Meek%5d) or the static abilities?

> 611.3c Continuous effects that modify characteristics of permanents do so simultaneously with the permanent entering the battlefield. They
> don’t wait until the permanent is on the battlefield and then change
> it. Because such effects apply as the permanent enters the
> battlefield, **they are applied before determining whether the permanent
> will cause an ability to trigger when it enters the battlefield.**
> *Example: A permanent with the static ability “All white creatures get
> +1/+1” is on the battlefield. A creature spell that would normally create a 1/1 white creature instead creates a 2/2 white creature. The
> creature doesn’t enter the battlefield as 1/1 and then change to 2/2.*

The 1/1 creature enters the battlefield as a 3/3, given that it's the type needed for [Vanquisher's Banner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVanquisher%27s%5d%2b%5bBanner%5d). So [Mentor of the Meek](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMentor%20of%20the%20Meek%5d) won't trigger.